# How to create interval facet in Solr Client

Tags: php, solr

I would like to set the following searching using Solr Client

```
select?facet=on&facet.field=Score&facet.interval=Score&f.Score.facet.interval.set=[0,10]&f.Score.facet.interval.set=[21,25]&f.Score.facet.interval.set=[26,35]&f.Score.facet.interval.set=[36,40]&f.Score.facet.interval.set=[41,45]&f.Score.facet.interval.set=[46,50]&q=*
```

The expected result is as follow:

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "Score":[
        "27",2,
        "41",3,
        ......
        "31",2]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{
      "Score":{
        "[0,10]":0,
        "[11,25]":12,
        "[26,35]":18,
        "[36,40]":9,
        "[41,45]":7,
        "[46,50]":2,}},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

After adding the facet field

```
$query->addFacetField('Score');
```

How can I set the facet interval? Also, how can I remove the result with 0 count in the facet_intervals?